# How to generate 11 char hash key for Sms Retriever with Google App signing not working

Tags: android

I have tried Mac-os and window

I have tried Mac-os and window

For window
keytool -exportcert -alias innodel -keystore certificate.jks | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.innodel 'cat' | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11

For MacOs
keytool -exportcert -alias innodel -keystore certificate.jks | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.innodel 'cat' | shasum -a 256 | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11

I have garnet e6k2hFMBFgH but it not working play store app.